# Delete all set variables postgresql dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have a lot of variables, which i create in pgsql request like @set variable=x.
I need to delete all variables i have so that the system don t remember any. And each time i run the code it used only variables, setted in this script

I could not find how to do it. Tried to exit dbeaver.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Postgres, [it's dbeaver evaluating those variables](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Client-Side-Scripting/)

Comment: According to https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Variables-panel/ you can find all the currently defined variables in a "variables panel"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.